# PHP powered multiple project issue tracker

Tags: php, wiki, issue-tracking, multiple-projects

I've been looking for an issue tracker that supports multiple projects and has a wiki.

I found Redmine, which fits what I need, and Trac, but I need one written in PHP.

I took a look at MantisBT, but that's not quite what I'm after.

Comment: I used JIRA for quite some time, it's pretty nice, better than Redmine and Basecamp from what I noticed. You can check it out, not sure if it will fit your needs.

Comment: My company uses https://www.activecollab.com/ ... it is PHP based. (not sure if it includes a wiki though)

Comment: Not much detail here. I expect you need one written in PHP because that's all you have hosting for? Is it not better to choose a system and then find suitable hosting for it, given how cheap hosting is these days? Why is MantisBT not what you are after?

Comment: I tried MantisBT last year and didn't quite like it much, the whole idea of hard coded HTML put me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Traq](http://traq.io) appears to fit your needs, PHP (version 5.3+), multiple projects and wiki.

Comment: I think I remember trying this a few years ago, wasn't so great, completely forgot about it, however the new version seems really a lot better. Thank you.